# Date validation check if the input date is less than the current date

Tags: php, html, date, validation

Good day, I am currently developing a hotel reservation website for a school project and I want to make a validation date for my date, the logic is when I input a date that is less than the date today it will show an error that the user has input a invalid date.

here is the code from the form:

```
<label> Arrival date </label>
              <input type = "date" name = "doa"  value="<?php $date; ?>">
                <span class = "error"><?php echo $error_date; ?></span>
```

here is the code from the validation but I can't do it properly please help me

```
if(empty($_POST['doa'])){
      $error_date = "This field is reqiured!";
        $error++;
    }
    else{
      $date = test_input($_POST['doa']);
      $dateInput = $_POST['doa'];
      $currenDate = date("d/m/y");
      $currenDate = date("d/m/y", strtotime($currenDate));
        if($currenDate == $dateInput){
          $error_date = "asdasd";
        }

    }
```

I've been solving this problem for a week now and I'm still solving it please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you. But, just like in Math, your units have to be the same. Are both your date values in the same units? And you should consider time zones, if applicable.

Comment: Just create the condition you formulated: `$currenDate > $dateInput`. Hint: `$currentDate` is a better variable name. It is easier to read if you use the variable to compare to first. So swap to `$dateInput < $currentDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I have to rename the awful *'doa'* name in your HTML first. You might know this means *'date of arrival'* but abbreviations like this only make your code far less readable.

```
<label> Arrival date </label>
<input type = "date" name = "arrival_date"  value="<?php $date; ?>">
<span class = "error"><?php echo $error_date; ?></span>
```

Then to your question. I assume that the `test_input()` does something useful, so I left it in. I checked [the documentation of <input type="date">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) and it shows that the date format is YYYY-MM-DD, so I used this. Note that I am using string comparison, not numeric comparison. That just happens to work for dates in this format, but in many other cases it won't.

```
if(empty($_POST['arrival_date'])) {
    $error_date = "This field is reqiured!";
    $error++;
} else {
    $arrivalDate = test_input($_POST['arrival_date']);
    if($arrivalDate < date("Y-m-d") {
        $error_date = "The date should be today or later";
        $error++;
    }
}
```